# Можно ли отключить механизм истекания ключей в redis

Tags: redis

Проблема
Есть активный redis с большим количеством ключей, имеющих малый срок жизни

Необходимо провести некоторую аналитику по значениям этих ключей

Есть возможность снимать дамп базы, однако при этом TTL никуда не девается и запуск аналитики с дампа на другом окружении - бесполезен.

Поэтому вопрос - есть ли возможность отключить механизма expire-инга ключей для Redis.

Answer (score 0):

[`PERSIST mykey`](https://redis.io/commands/persist) вам не подойдёт?

Comment: Нет, не подойдет.
Причина в том, что на его выполнение тоже уйдет время.
 
Безусловно, можно его использовать в Pipeline, который выполнится единой транзакцией, однако это всеравно не гарантированное решение и есть шанс потерять часть данных.